# Excel VBA Cell condition not being met

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following snippet of a spreadsheet:

[image]

When I press the Yesterday button, I want the button to find all the cells that have either Today or Tomorrow as values and replace them with Yesterday, namely `=TODAY()-1`.

Once this is solved, the other two buttons become trivial to solve.

Here is the current macro:

```
Sub Yesterday_Click()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim CellRange As Range

    Dim Today As String
    Dim Tomorrow As String
    Dim Yesterday As String

    Today = "=TODAY()"
    Tomorrow = "=TODAY()+1"
    Yesterday = "=TODAY()-1"

    'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
    LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set CellRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    For Each cell In CellRange
        If cell.Value = Today Or cell.Value = Tomorrow Then
            cell.Value = Yesterday
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

If I add a watch to `cell.Value`, the result of `cell.Value` is `2015-05-04`, instead of `=TODAY()`.

How do I get Excel to evaluate what I wrote in the cell, namely `=TODAY()`, instead of the value the cell contains as a result of the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me weather you want a formula in your cell or a value.

For a formula use

```
cell.Formula = "=TODAY()"
```

Or a value use

```
cell.Value = Evaluate("=TODAY()")
```

Comment: Hi Peh, I want the formula to be replaced. Excel itself then evaluates the formula to the correct value.

Comment: @wickyd To replace the formula use the first code in my answer above.

Comment: Hi Peh, That was exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim Yesterday As String

Today = "=TODAY()"
Tomorrow = "=TODAY()+1"
Yesterday = "=TODAY()-1"

'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Find the last non-blank cell in row 1
LastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set CellRange = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

For Each cell In CellRange
    Debug.Print cell.Address
    Debug.Print cell.Value
    If cell.Value = Date Or cell.Value = Date + 1 Then
    cell.Formula = Yesterday
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```